# How to run npm module (puppeteer) in a VSCode chrome live-server?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

**The problem**

I am using a npm module in VS Code which works with node.js and throws a `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` when using the live-server extension offered in VS Code.

**Related posts**

Other posts suggest that I should use browserify. The tutorials that I found for browserify seemed to create an individual live server. I am looking for a solution (if possible) that would allow me to use the live-server extension. (I don't quite understand how to create my own server- I am using the live-server extension because that is what I am familiar with so far. I am open to further suggestions.)

*More Context:* I am running a webpage using the VS Code live-server extension that needs to get data from another website using the puppeteer module.

Comment: To my understanding, Live Server is simply a lightweight web server that runs and listens for file changes. Just make puppeteer go to that url.

Comment: Node.js is for the server side. Browsers do not implement require. For that to work you need to bundle your code with either Browserify or Webpack. This link might help you: https://github.com/browserify/browserify#external-requires

Comment: @Bren Could you explain what you mean by make puppeteer go to that url? I'm not quite picking up your suggestion.

Comment: @Justin when you open Live Server, it opens a browser correct? That url is what you're after. Try seeing what happens if you call goto() with puppeteer.

Comment: @Bren I'm confused as to why I would want to go to that url. I am using pupetter to scrape data from a different website. Once I scrape data from that website, I hope to use that data to change the html webpage and display the webpage using liveserver. Does that clarify my post?

Answer (score 0):

I personally battled with this same issue this week and came to the conclusion that the puppeteer library can only work server side as a cloud function or by running it locally in your terminal using `node "filename"`. Theres some security web protocols that dont allow scraping from the client side.